# Notification class does not work properly

Tags: java, android

I created a simple service and now I am making a notification for this. I am writing a class for notification. After writing all code, three lines are underlined with red color one is this function `getSystemService(ns);` at line 14, second is this one `getApplicationContext();` on line 20 and the third one is again same function as first one but on line 31 in `cancelNotification()` function. here is my complete code

```
package com.zafar.batterynotify;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Notify {
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    public void initNotification() {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        CharSequence tickerText = "Service Started";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "Ongoing service";
        CharSequence contentText = "This is service is ongoing";
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, BatteryNotify.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    public void cancelNotification() {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
        mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    }
}
```

**Edit** Updated code

My service class

```
package com.zafar.batterynotify;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BatteryService extends Service {
Notify notification = new Notify();
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    notification.initNotification(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    notification.cancelNotification(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

Notify class

```
package com.zafar.batterynotify;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Notify {
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

public void initNotification(Context actContext) {
    //String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    //Context context = actContext.getApplicationContext();
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = actContext.getSystemService(ns);
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    CharSequence tickerText = "Service Started";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    Context context = actContext.getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence contentTitle = "Ongoing service";
    CharSequence contentText = "This is service is ongoing";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, BatteryNotify.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}

public void cancelNotification(Context actContext) {
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = actContext.getSystemService(ns);
    mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your context from calling Activity or service to your class and use it:

```
    public void initNotification(Context actContext) {
    //...
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = actContext.getSystemService(ns);
    //...
    }

    public void cancelNotification(Context actContext) {
        //...
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = actContext.getSystemService(ns);
        //...
    }
```

Comment: Please see my update. I changed it but still does not work. Noe red underline is on two lines. at line 15 getSystemService(ns); only under ns in parenthesis and second one is in cancelNotification function line number 32 actContext.getSystemService(ns);

Comment: do not comment `String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;`

Comment: yeah that is fixed now but the problem is now in service class. Now both the functions which I am calling i.e. initNotification and cancelNotification are unlined with red line. When I hover over this it says Change initNotification to initNotification(String) from initNotification(Context).

Comment: you must use ns as input parameter

Comment: ok if I do as you say like NotificationManager mNotificationManager = actContext.getSystemService(ns) thenit underline the whole line. but when I use NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) actContext.getSystemService(ns) then it is fine. Secondly could you please see my service class above. It also shows red line on two places

Comment: yes `NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) actContext.getSystemService(ns)` is OK. Where do you have red lines? What is their messages?

Comment: In my service class at line notification.initNotification(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); and notification.cancelNotification(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Comment: Change it to `notification.cancelNotification(this);` and `notification.initNotification(this);
`

Comment: Ok now I got errors in my logcat. Please see my logcat above.

Comment: use `return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);` instead of `return START_STICKY;` and determine the answer of your question and open a new thread for more questions.

Answer (score 0):

don't try to use `getApplicationContext()`, instead create `MyApplication` class, inherited from the `Application`, then inside that class do the following:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
        .........
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return instance;
    }
```

After that, you may use `MyApplication.getContext()` anywhere if you need a context and don't have an `Activity` lying around.